# How can I use JDBCTemplate from Spring JDBC in a Swing desktop application?

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I use a lot of JDBC code in my Swing desktop application. Now I read about `JDBCTemplate` from Spring in `Spring in Action` and it looks like a nice API for working with JDBC.

But Spring JDBC seem to need some XML configuration files for beans. Is there any way I can use JDBCTemplate without these XML configuration files (e.g. with annotations)? Or how can I use this JdbcTemplate in a Swing desktop application for database access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a Spring Context without XML by creating a **@Configuration** anotated java class and create the Spring Context using the **AnnotationConfigApplicationContext** class to load the config

see [Spring JavaConfig](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html#new-java-configuration) for a code sample.

Answer (score 2):

While using Spring as the backbone of your application certainly has merit, and indeed annotation-based configuration can free you from 'XML hell', if you just want to use `JdbcTemplate` 'raw' there's nothing preventing you from doing so.

Just make sure you supply it with a valid `DataSource`, such as `PGPoolingDataSource` for example, if you're using PostgreSQL. If your JDBC vendor does not provide a `DataSource` implementation, then feel free to use Spring's `SimpleDriverDataSource`.

For example:

```
DataSource ds = new SimpleDriverDataSource(LegacyDriver.class,
    "jdbc:legacy://database", "username", "password");
JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
// Use jdbc to do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though its technically possible - it would defeat the purpose and design of Spring based application. 
My suggestion would be to start using Spring framework as a backbone for you application. I promise you that your application will only benefit from using it (better design, clear separation of concerns, better testability etc ). Setting up JbdcTemplate using Spring context is almost trivial.

You already reading 'Spring in Action' - just start using it :)

Take a look at [Spring Reference Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/) - the best Spring resource, period